# Can multiple Git clients be used on the same repository?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I currently am using TortoiseGit from my Windows development machine. My repository is located on BitBucket. Recently I have been looking at other Git clients as I find TortoiseGit a bit confusing.

Since Git information and meta-data is stored in `.git` folders I was wondering if I can use other Git clients on my current branch. If possible are there any disadvantages to doing this?

Comment: Yes, you can use. No, there are no disadvantages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you switch to a different client, say you were using command-line yesterday and TortoiseGit today? Sure, why not. Possibly somewhere there is (or maybe will be) a client that stores things differently and than you'd have some problems, but a smoke-check (aka doing equivalent of `git log` and checking that all your commits are there) should be enough.

But do yourself a favor and don't run both at the same time. Close all TortoiseGit instances before attempting your IDE plugin. At least when it comes to RW operations (RO are generally safe). While the original `git` binary is safe for concurrent access, I won't assume it about every other implementation in the wild. Most probably it won't harm you, but why take chances in the first place?

Comment: "Why take the chance in the first place"? So I can compare the advantages and disadvantages of Git clients and see how they work for me in my development environment.

Comment: @webworm This sentence was about trying them all _at once_, that is concurrently running different implementations. Not about trying different clients one after another, or event running different implementations at the same time, but only one of them actively writing to the repository.