# Git 1.9.1 and 2.5.4 compatibility when working on the same repository

Tags: git, macos, compatibility, linux-mint

I have a repository that is stored on Dropbox which is shared between all my machines. On OSX I have Git 2.5.4 installed (courtesy of some bloke at apple) and on Mint I have 1.9.1 installed. I'm just worried that some of the meta-data that gets stored in the .git file might be different across the versions and that I'm going to run into problems?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045594/can-multiple-git-clients-be-used-on-the-same-repository) seems to point towards it being fine - however this was just Git clients, not versions?

Is my setup going to be fine? Or is there a better way to manage my files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can multiple Git clients be used on the same repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045594/can-multiple-git-clients-be-used-on-the-same-repository)

Comment: That's the one that I included in my question. It's dealing with clients not versions. However this question that I've just come across: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884027/different-versions-of-git-between-developers
May be a duplicate? It seems that it's ok if you're in the same master version 1.x or 2.x but going between them might cause problems?

Comment: Some of the commands may be slightly different, but I don't think you'll hit any compatible issues with what's in .git for example

Comment: Just a bit of an update for anyone who might find this later. Started hitting problems with dropbox clashes and git getting fatal errors. 

I updated my git version on linux to 2.7.1 and now host my repository on bitbucket. Everything seems to be working great now :) 

(side note: can't use OSX anymore because Gurobi doesn't support python 3.5... back to Win10 + Linux for me - caused all kinds of line-ending problems. But that's another story haha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since every git clone is its it own repo you will not have any problems working with multiple clients on the same repo.

In your case

> I have a repository that is stored on Dropbox which is shared between all my machines

I assume you have a single folder shared between different end devices in which each device has a different git version. It might be a problem since each new version might have some bug fixed which handle files differently, there are new features which change the way git store information in the internal folder

For example: `git bisect` was updated and since version 2.7 the internal storage if the bisect data was updated.

Git 2.5 introduced working tree on the main stream as part of the official version and not under the contrib folder.

So you should accept differences between the versions and its better to upgrade your git clients to be the same over all your devices.